# public abstract or abstract public in java

Tags: java, oop, abstract, public

what is the difference between:

```
 1 - public abstract function();
 2 - abstract public function();
```

Comment: There is no difference.

Comment: Nothing. The conventional order is `public abstract` though.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't differences.
Only the syntax.